# Applying "Create New Google Drive Folder" script to last x rows of a GoogleSheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms, shared-directory

By applying a lot of the techniques I learned from the folks here in Stack Overflow, I was able to put together a script that creates a new named folder in Google Drive each time a new form is submitted. The script only executes for the last form submitted (last row), in order to keep it from looping. However, there are occasions where multiple forms are submitted at once, or Google's server slows down, and it results in rows being skipped, and folders not being created for my users.

Currently, I use the LastFew row (5th row) to address these cases manually (eg "last -1" to fill the 2nd to last row). But I need to be able to rely on this script when I'm not around.

The most rows I've seen skipped is 3. To prevent this, I would like to find a way for the script to automatically scan, and create folders, for the last 5 rows where a folder has not been created as indicated by "Done" in column 142.

I haven't been able to find an applicable solution in my research. So here goes:

```
function HRfolderCreator(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Form Responses 1');
  var Fvals = sheet.getRange("A1:A").getValues();
  var last = Fvals.filter(String).length;//last form received
  var LastFew = last; // add "-1" to create folder for the form before the last row. The larger the number, the farther back it will go
  var range = sheet.getRange(LastFew, 142); //get range of "HR Folder Created" column, where "done" is indicated when a folder is complete. 
  var values = range.getValues(); //get values "Done" column 
  //Below is where the script finds the last form entry where a folder has not been created
  for (var row=0; row<values.length; row++){ 
    if(!values[row].join("")){ //for the LastFew row where "Done" does not exist, create a new folder

      //Below, if a folder has not been created for the last form received, it will be created using the commands below
      Logger.log('LastFew'+LastFew);

      var TimeStamp = sheet.getRange(LastFew,1).getValue();   // get timestamp code
      var eLastName = sheet.getRange(LastFew,57).getValue();  // get Employee's Last NameID
      var eFirstName = sheet.getRange(LastFew,58).getValue(); // get Employee's Last NameID
      var PosName = sheet.getRange(LastFew, 68).getValue();   // get Position Name
      var AltPosName = sheet.getRange(LastFew, 69).getValue(); // get alternate Position Name 
      var eID = sheet.getRange(LastFew,56).getValue();//get Employee's Last NameID
      var ReqEmail = sheet.getRange(LastFew, 2).getValue();//get Analyst's email address
      var Various = sheet.getRange(LastFew, 49).getValue();//get "Various Employees" if multiple employees involved
      var folder = DriveApp.createFolder(PosName + AltPosName + Various + eLastName + ', ' + eFirstName + ' - ' + eID + ' ('+TimeStamp + ')' ); //Creates folder name based on Employee's Last Name, First Name - Employee ID (Timestamp)
      var rFolder = folder.getName();    // retrieves the name of the folder created in the var folder line 
      var rFolderId = folder.getId();    // retrieves the ID of the folder created in the var folder line
      var rFolderUrl = folder.getUrl();  // retrieves the URL of the folder created in the var folder line
      var RequestTime = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "PST", "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm");
      sheet.getRange(LastFew, 138).setValue(ReqEmail);
      sheet.getRange(LastFew, 139).setValue(rFolder); //Places the name of the folder retrieved from 'var aFolder' in column the column number listed (eg. "(last, 82). 
      sheet.getRange(LastFew, 140).setValue(rFolderId);
      sheet.getRange(LastFew, 141).setValue(rFolderUrl);
      sheet.getRange(LastFew, 142).setValue("Done").clearFormat().setComment(new Date()); //Indicates "Done" in the final column when a folder has been created. 
      sheet.getRange(LastFew, 143).setValue(RequestTime);


      //Add request folders to Department folder
      var DeptFolderID = 'xxxxxxxx' //This is the Location ID for the Department's main folder. First create a folder in Google Drive, copy the ID of the new folder, and paste here. 
      var DeptFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(DeptFolderID); //Retrieve folder ID for Department's folder

      var requestFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(rFolderId); //Retrieve Folder ID for Request Folder

      DeptFolder.addFolder(requestFolder);//put request folder in Department folder

      DriveApp.getRootFolder().removeFolder(requestFolder);//take request folder out of Google Drive
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: instead of using the last fifth rows, why not just use your function to scan all of the rows not makred with "Done" in order to always try to create these folder again whenever it ran? You can then schedule it to run by a timer or UI trigger so it can be scanned very frequently

Comment: I initially ran a script that scanned all the rows, but it turned out to be very inefficient - especially as the number of form responses increased. The reason why the efficiency matters is because a merge document, and an email notification, is created each time a form is submitted. If the folder script is too slow, the "on submit" merge document will not include the necessary folder info.

Comment: Do you need to trigger the full scan every time when form is submitted? If not create a time-driven trigger to run it once per night or fortnight https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers